# how to convert the below subquery into joins using one update statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below is a complete query I have and the ultimate aim is to update the claim table. But it should be only one statement without any subquery, only joins are allowed because I am going to run this in an appliance which won't support subquery:

```
DECLARE @DecWdrwn as TABLE(CtryId smallint, CmId int, DecWdrwnDt int);
WITH s AS 
(
    SELECT  
        Ctryid,CmId,Dt,
        ISNULL((
            SELECT  max(CmHistDtTmId) 
            FROM    ClaimHistory l 
            WHERE   St = 3 
                    AND l.Ctryid = c.Ctryid 
                    AND l.CmId = c.CmId)
            , 0) MaxDec, 
        ISNULL((
            SELECT  max(CmHistDtTmId) 
            FROM    ClaimHistory l 
            WHERE   St = 7 
                    AND l.Ctryid = c.Ctryid 
                    AND l.CmId = c.CmId)
            , 0) MaxSet
    FROM 
        ClaimHistory c
    WHERE 
        St =3
)

INSERT  INTO @DecWdrwn
SELECT  CtryId, CmId, Max(Dt) DecDt 
FROM    s
WHERE   MaxSet > MaxDec
GROUP   BY CtryId,CmId
```

Your response is much appreciated...

```
UPDATE  Claims 
SET     CmDclnWdwnDt = (
            SELECT  DecWdrwnDt 
            FROM    @DecWdrwn d 
            WHERE   d.CmId = Claims.CmId 
                    AND d.CtryId = Claims.CtryId
            )
WHERE   EXISTS (
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    @DecWdrwn d 
        WHERE   d.CmId = Claims.CmId 
                AND d.CtryId = Claims.CtryId
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try [INNER JOIN Update](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3630381/MS-SQL-Joins-Part-3.htm):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.CmDclnWdwnDt = b.DecWdrwnDt
FROM Claims a, @DecWdrwn b
WHERE a.CmId = b.CmId AND
        a.CtryId =b.CtryId
```